# Problema con inner join sql

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, join, conjuntos

Me estoy volviendo loco, he probado en varias bases de datos y no me funciona a ver si me podeis ayudar.

```
select 'Tienda.Codigo_de_barras' from "Tienda" inner join "Online" 
on 'Tienda.Codigo_de_barras' ='Online.Codigo_de_barras';
```

El codigo consiste en ver que productos estan disponible online y en la tienda. El codigo compila pero como resultado da una tabla vacia, y segun los datos que he introducido debe de dar varios productos.
Las dos variables codigo de barras son de tipo char (10), he probado a cambiar el = por un LIKE pero da el mismo resultado

Comment: Postgresql suele dar problemas con mayúsculas/minúsculas. ¿Tus tablas se llaman `Tienda` o `tienda` o `TIENDA`, ... `Online` u `online` u `ONLINE`, quizá `onLine`?  en la consulta conviene que escribas los nombres de tabla como existen en la base de datos.

Comment: Esta todo revisado y es correcto

Comment: Prueba con `LEFT JOIN` en lugar de `INNER JOIN` y verifica que la consulta se ejecuta en el `schema` donde están las tablas. Supongo que habrás quitado las comillas en los nombres de tabla.

Comment: he comprobado todo y sigue dando error. Tambien he probado `left join` da el error `ERROR:  falta una entrada para la tabla «Tienda» en la cláusula FROM`

Comment: ¿Podrías ejecutar los siguientes comandos en tu manejador de BD y compartirlos en la pregunta? **`SHOW CREATE TABLE Tienda;`** y también **`SHOW CREATE TABLE Online;`**. Puedes [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/158010/edit), poniendo el resultado de cada consulta para analizar la constitución de tus tablas.

Answer (score 1):

Tu consulta SQL esta mal diseñana elimina las comillas simples y dobles simples en los nombre de los campos y tablas:

```
select Tienda.Codigo_de_barras from Tienda inner join Online
on Tienda.Codigo_de_barras = Online.Codigo_de_barras;
```

Comment: Me sale otro error  ERROR:  falta una entrada para la tabla «tienda» en la cláusula FROM. Estoy progrmando en postgreSQL, no se si existe alguna diferencia con mySQL

Comment: Que motor de base de datos estas utilizado?

Comment: estoy usando pgadmin 4

Comment: me suena a que el nombre de las tablas va en minusculas, ya probaste utlizando el query en minusculas?

Answer (score 1):

**¡Hola!**

Veo que estás intentando relacionar dos tablas a través de juntas, siendo que éstas no están hechas para realizarse sobre tipos de datos char o varchar (cadenas de caracteres). Las juntas están diseñadas para realizarse sobre campos numéricos (int4, int8, numeric, etc).

**Pregunta**: ¿En tu definición de datos (DDL) posees un campo numérico que una a ambas tablas?

En caso de ser **positivo**, te recomiendo que ejecutes la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT T.Codigo_De_Barras
FROM Tienda as T INNER JOIN Online as O ON (T.id = O.id)
WHERE T.Codigo_De_Barras LIKE '%LO QUE BUSCAS%'
```

Puedes variar entre el uso del "%" dentro del LIKE o incluso, usar simplemente el "=" si conoces específicamente los valores.

En caso de ser **negativo**, recomiendo que replantees el diseño de tu schema en la base de datos. Recuerda que usar una cadena de caracteres como identificador de una tabla nunca es recomendable. ¿Por qué?. Porque consume demasiados caracteres y generará mal uso de almacenamiento en todas las tablas que se refieran entre sí.

Espero que te haya servido, en caso contrario explaya más te escenario con tus sentencias DDL.

¡Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

¿Podrías agregar desde que programa estas trabajando con SQL? He realizado una prueba en PostgreSQL v12 y te comento que tienes que especificar correctamente la sintaxis.
Te ubico un ejemplo que se asemeja a tus datos y funciona correctamente:

```
SELECT "Tienda"."Codigo_de_barras"
FROM "PruebaSQL"."Tienda" 
INNER JOIN "PruebaSQL"."Online" 
    ON "Tienda"."Codigo_de_barras" = "Online"."Codigo_de_barras"
```